# Javascript Dsiplay 2 strings in one alert

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to display 2 or 3 strings in one alert in JS? here is my code:

```
var num = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
alert(num [0]);
```

i want to display one , two, in one alert or one pop up in browser

Comment: Did you try `alert(num[0] + num[1] + num[2])`?

Comment: its working using this code alert(num[0] + num[1] + num[2]) but but i'ts showing one,two,three, what i do is alert(num [0] + num[1] + ''); and it's working fine, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var num = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

alert(num [0] + " , " + num [1]);
```

Similarly you can use a for loop and construct the final massage and then display it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Malindu, It's working perfectly using this sample, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Alert(num[0] + '  ' + num[1]);

Comment: it's working using this code Alert(num[0] + ' ' + alert[1]); but i'm getting undefined result,

Comment: Sorry, it's alert(num[0] + '  ' + num[1]);

Comment: it's working using this code alert(num [0] + num[1] + ''); Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it

Comment: it's working fine with this syntax : alert(num[0] + ' ' + num[1]) Thanks @ Hector, appreciate it